# Selecting the right cloud storage option on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am an entry level developer in a startup. I am trying to deploy a text classifier on GCP. For storing inputs(training data) and outputs, I am struggling to find the right storage option.

My data isn't huge in terms of columns but is fairly huge in terms of instances. It could even be just key-value pairs. My use case is to retrieve each entity from just one particular column from the DB, apply some classification on it and store the result in the corresponding column and update the DB. Our platform requires a DB which can handle a lot of small queries at once without much delay. Also, the data is completely unrelational.

I looked into GCP's article of choosing a storage option but couldn't narrow down my options to any specific answer. Would love to get some advice on this.

Comment: You can look at `MongoDB` and `Google Cloud Datastore`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Google's "Choosing a Storage Option" guide: https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/

Your data is structured, your main goal is not analytics, your data isn't relational, you don't mostly need mobile SDKs, so you should probably use Cloud Datastore. That's a great choice for durable key-value data.

Comment: How does BigTable fare against Datastore with respect to my use-case?

Comment: What if my data is unstructured? Would BigTable be a better option then?

Comment: If your data is completely unstructured, as in it has an ID and then the data is some arbitrary bytes, like an image file or something, Google Cloud Storage may be your best bet, especially if the data values are sizable (megabytes).

Comment: it's a text classifier. Training data does not have images, just small paragraphs of labelled text.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, these are the **`storage options available`**. May be in future it can be more or less.
[image]

Depending on choice, you can select your storage option which is best suited.
**SOURCE: Linux Academy**